# Fill in uneven sized lists in Python

Tags: python, pandas, list, list-comprehension

I have a 2D-List contains unequal size lengths, like this:

```
lst = [[1,2,3],[-1,2,4],[0,2],[2,-3,6]]
```

I use this code to insert a 0 if element size less 3:

```
newlist = [val.insert(1,0) for val in lst if len(val)<3]
```

But I just got an empty `newlist` and the original `lst` was inserted into a `0`.

```
>>> lst = [[1,2,3],[-1,2,4],[0,2],[2,-3,6]]
>>> newlist = [val.insert(1,0) for val in lst if len(val)<3]
>>> newlist
[None]
>>> lst
[[1, 2, 3], [-1, 2, 4], [0, 0, 2], [2, -3, 6]]
```

I don't want use old `lst` list value because if modified value can return to `newlist`, I can directly use it convert to a DataFrame like this:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([val.insert(1,0) for val in lst if len(val)<3])
```

So, how do I do this? And I hope the code can be written in a one-liner.

Comment: `list.insert` is an in-place method; it does not return anything, it simply modifies the calling object. Furthermore, you're using `v` and `val` interchangeably in your code which will obviously result in issues.

Comment: val.insert probably returns None. Placing the if in the end also discards lists that are already length 3.

Comment: ddejohn, sorry for mistake of varible 'v' , just edited

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are getting None as the value for `newlist` because `val.insert(1,0)` returns `None` as the output.

Try this instead,

```
lst = [[1,2,3],[-1,2,4],[0,2],[2,-3,6]]
new_list = [i + [0] if len(i) < 3 else i for i in lst]
print(new_list)
```

Output -

```
[[1, 2, 3], [-1, 2, 4], [0, 2, 0], [2, -3, 6]]
```

Comment: Does not work if the inner list are of length 0 or 1.

Comment: Cool, but it seems only insert a 0 into tail of item, is there a way insert a 0 to middle location?

Answer (score 4):

The problem in your code is that `val.insert(1,0)` mutates the list in place, and returns None.

My suggestion is shown below. It might not be exactly the output you expected (because it returns an array of tuples), but it will probably serve for your purpose:

```
from itertools import zip_longest
list(zip(*zip_longest(*lst, fillvalue=0)))

# output: 
# [(1, 2, 3), (-1, 2, 4), (0, 2, 0), (2, -3, 6)]
```

Explanation:

`[zip_longest][1]` aggregates elements from each sequence, and if they are of uneven length, missing values are filled-in with `fillvalue`. By using the `*` operator, each inner list is passed as a separate parameter to the function.

After zip_longest is done and missing are filled, I am zipping it again (the result was transposed by the first zip).

Comment: You can use it like this: `df = pd.DataFrame(zip(*zip_longest(*lst, fillvalue=0)))`

Answer (score 1):

Keep things simple. Your original approach was valid, but just use a classical loop:

```
lst = [[1,2,3],[-1,2,4],[0,2],[2,-3,6]]
# if needed, keep a copy
# old_lst = lst.copy()

for l in lst:
    if len(l)<3:
        l.insert(1,0)
        
pd.DataFrame(lst)
```

Output:

```
   0  1  2
0  1  2  3
1 -1  2  4
2  0  0  2
3  2 -3  6
```